# azure website warning: "encountered loading management data"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

in my azure panel i received the following warning :

"Warnings encountered loading management data."[image]

any one has any idea what is the reason of this warning ?

regards

Comment: Does the `Details (i)` button in the bottom right give any further indication of what the issue may be?  Otherwise it may be a transient issue with the management portal itself.  There's no indication of this on the [Azure Service Dashboard](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/) however, it may be worth contacting [Azure Support](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/options/)

Comment: this is the message in details : There was an error encountered getting webspaces for subscription

Comment: I am getting same error, don't know why

Comment: @Manoj Thanks for replay, still wait for Microsoft support team

Comment: I am getting the same error. I don't know why

Comment: automatically resolved for me,